# Android Calendar doesn't add Day

Tags: android, kotlin, date, calendar, days

```
    val dayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    dayCalendar.time = entryDateC.time
    for (day in 1..howManyDays) {
        dayCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        if (!disabledDays.contains(dayCalendar)) {
            disabledDays.add(dayCalendar)
        }
    }
```

I checked and made sure that `howManyDays` is 30 by logging `day` inside the for loop. What I'm trying to do, is to add to the `disabledDays` each day for one month after the `entryDate`, but this code doesn't seem to work. All what is added to the `disabledDays` is one date. Any help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I clearly stated my problem

Comment: You are always trying to add the same `dayCalendar` instance so, after the first insertion, `disabledDays.contains(dayCalendar)` will always return true. You could create a copy of the calendar each time and add that one, but do you really need a list of calendar objects? Maybe there's a better solution if you explain what is the purpose of this computation.

Comment: If you know a better solution, please tell me

Comment: I don't know how the result of this code is supposed to be used, so I can't suggest a different solution. But again, if you want a list of calendar objects, you need to create a new instance each time instead of mutating and using the same one.

Comment: I have a material calendar view, and I'm trying to add the the `dayCalendar` 
to the `disabledDates` and then remove from them specific dates which I don't want them to be disabled. So I"m adding all hte period, and then removing the dates I desire

Comment: Consider switching to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If for API level under 26, you will need core library desugaring to make that work. The old-fashioned and poorly designed `Calendar` is really very unsuited to what you are trying. For one thing there are so many ways two `Calendar` objects may differ even though they denote the same day.

Comment: All what is added to the `disabledDays` is one date

Comment: I mean, if you use `java.util.Calendar`, of course your code isn't going to work.

Comment: `tomorrow.datesUntil(tomorrow.plusDays(30)).collect(Collectors.toList())`. The `datesUntil` method produces a stream of dates until the specified end date exclusive, so even when starting from tomorrow we still need to add 30 (not 29).

Comment: Thanks for specifying observed behaviour. It seems to confirm what @gpunto said. When adding information, please always do it *in question itself* so we have everything in one place. Don’t expect your readers to read through all the comments. (This time only I pasted it in there for you.)